# How to modify a List element at a given index

Tags: elm

What I've done (with some help from a friend) is create a function that takes a `List`, `Int` for the index, and a function to be applied to the element at the specified index.  It's similar to `Map` but instead of applying a function to every element, it applies it to only one element.

So my questions are:

- Does this function already exist in the core somewhere?  We couldn't find it.
- If not, is there a better way of accomplishing this than how we have done it?

Here's the code:

```elm
import Html exposing (text)

main =
    let
        m = {arr=[1,5,3], msg=""}
    in
        text (toString (getDisplay m 4 (\x -> x + 5)))


type alias Model =
    { arr : List (Int)
    , msg : String
    }


getDisplay : Model -> Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Model
getDisplay model i f = 
    let 
        m = (changeAt model.arr i f)
    in
        case m of
            Ok val -> 
                {model | arr = val, msg = ""}
            Err err -> 
                {model | arr = [], msg = err}


changeAt : List a -> Int -> (a -> a) -> Result String (List a)
changeAt l i func = 
    let
        f j x = if j==i then func x else x
    in
        if i < (List.length l) && i >= 0 then
            Ok(List.indexedMap f l)
        else
            Err "Bad index"
```

NOTE: [Elm discourages indexing Lists, as they are linked lists under the hood: to retrieve the 1001th element, you have to first visit all 1000 previous elements.](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/4821xv/accessing_a_list_element_by_index_number/d0gwhdy) Nonetheless, if you wanted to do it, this is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List.indexedMap` is a good way to do what you're describing.

However, since you mention the downside of having to visit all preceding elements in a list, the reality in your example is actually a little worse, if indeed you are super worried about performance.

Your list is actually traversed fully at least two times, regardless of whether the index exists or not. The simple act of asking for the length of a linked list has to traverse the entire list. Check out the source code, [`length` is implemented in terms of a `foldl`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3.0.0/src/List.elm#L225).

Furthermore, `List.indexedMap` traverses the entire list at least once. I say, *at least once*, since the source of `indexedMap` also [calls the `length` function](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3.0.0/src/List.elm#L141) in addition to using `map`. If we're lucky, the `length` call is memoized (I'm not familiar enough with Elm internals to know whether it is or not, hence the *at least* comment). The `map` itself traverses the entire list when called, unlike Haskell which evaluates things lazily, only as much as necessary.

And if you use `indexedMap`, the whole list is indexed regardless of the position you are interested in. That is, even if you want to apply the function at index zero, the entire list is indexed.

If you actually want to reduce the number of traversals to a minimum, you're going to (at this time) have to implement your own function and you'll have to do it without relying on `length` or `indexedMap`.

Here is an example of a `changeAt` function which avoids unnecessary traversals and if it finds the position, it stops traversing the list.

```elm
changeAt : List a -> Int -> (a -> a) -> Result String (List a)
changeAt l i func =
  if i < 0 then
    Err "Bad Index"
  else
    case l of
      [] ->
        Err "Not found"
      (x::xs) ->
        if i == 0 then
          Ok <| func x :: xs
        else
          Result.map ((::) x) <| changeAt xs (i - 1) func
```

It's not terribly pretty, but if you want to avoid unnecessarily walking through the list - multiple times - then you might want to go with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [the `set` function for Arrays](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Array#set). Instead of using a List, which is inefficient as you described, this structure is better suited to your use case.

Here's an efficient implementation of the function you're looking for:

```
changeAt : Int -> (a -> a) -> Array a -> Array a
changeAt i f array =
case get i array of
    Just item ->
        set i (f item) array
    Nothing ->
        array
```

Also note that the [data structure is the last argument](http://package.elm-lang.org/help/design-guidelines#the-data-structure-is-always-the-last-argument) in this implementation.

`Array` is mentioned in the link in your question, but nobody on this thread had explicitly mentioned this option yet.